# Need Help in Coordinate Geometry (Straight Lines)

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

A line $L$  is drawn from the point $P\equiv(4,3)$  to meet the parallel lines $L_1: 3x + 4y + 15 =0$  and $L_2 = 3x + 4y + 5 =0$ at points $A$  and $B$ respectively.

From $A$, a line perpendicular to $L$  is drawn meeting the line $L_2$ at $C$ . Similarly from point $B$, a line perpendicular to $L$ is drawn meeting the line  $L_1$ at $D$. A parallelogram $ACBD$  is formed.

Find the equations(s) of the line $L$ such that the area of the parallelogram $ACBD$ is least.

Answer (score 3):

The distance $BE$ between the parallel lines $L_1$ and $L_2$ is easily found and is $2$.

Let the angle which the line $L$ makes with $L_1$ be $\theta$. Simple trigonometry tells you that $AE=2\cot\theta$ and $CE=2\tan\theta$. Then the area of $\Delta ABC$ becomes:
$$area=\frac{1}{2} base \cdot height$$
$$\Delta=\frac{1}{2} BE\cdot AC=\frac{1}{2} BE\cdot (AE+CE)=2|\cot\theta+\tan\theta|$$
The area of paralleogram is twice of $\Delta$, so it will be minimum when $\Delta$ is minimum. It is evident that $\Delta$ is minimum at $\theta=\dfrac{\pi}{4}$. At this value of $\theta$, clearly $\Delta_{min}=4.$

Now use the formula for angle between two lines to calculate the slope of line $L$:
$$\pm\tan\theta={m_1-m_2 \over 1+m_1m_2}=\pm1$$
Take $m_1$ as the slope of $L_1$ and solve the equation to get two values of $m_2$. To obtain both the equations of the line $L$, use point-slope form of line since it passes through $P\equiv(4,3)$.

[image]

Wait for the GIF to load, it looks cool. You can see how the area approaches the minimum value of 8 twice and goes to infinity when the line $L$ becomes perpendicular to $L_1$.

Comment: That $*$ is the symbol for convolution. You should fix that to $\cdot$ or $\times$